# How to send tcp packet through echo redirection through interface

Tags: bash

The 10.x.x.x is the same machine on interface eth0

When I run this command

```
echo -n "hello" > /dev/tcp/10.x.x.x/8080
```

the packet is delivered to 127.0.0.1 and not 10.x.x.x

How can it be set so that it goes directly to 10.x.x.x interface eth0 and not lo